# View not getting the new value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have this service to keep the status of the app up to date.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('reportApp')
  .service('Status', function Status() {

    this.appStatus = {};

    // Status
    this.get = function(){

        this.appStatus = {

            menu:{
                right:{
                    activeOption: 'datax'
                },
                left:{

                }
            },
            section:{
                selectedSection: null
            }

        };

        return this.appStatus;

    };

    this.setActiveOptionRightMenu = function(menu){

        this.appStatus.menu.right.activeOption = menu.id;

    };

    this.setActiveSection = function(section){

        this.appStatus.section.selectedSection = section;

    };

    // ####################################


  });
```

In my main controller I have this:

```
$scope.openRightMenu = function(menu){

    Status.setActiveOptionRightMenu(menu);
    $scope.menu = Status.get().menu;

};

$scope.menu = Status.get().menu;
```

When controller load in the first moment it gets the right default value:

```
$scope.menu = Status.get().menu;
```

In the first moment I'm expecting **activeOption: 'datax'** and it's right. But after the event click in the view calling **openRightMenu** the view does not update the new value. If I put a breakpoint inside the **setActiveOptionRightMenu** I can see the new value being setted, but after that looks like the view ignore the new value and keep using the old one.

Comment: Can you include a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your get function you are overriding `this.appStatus`:

```
 // Status
this.get = function(){

    this.appStatus = {

        menu:{
            right:{
                activeOption: 'datax'
            },
            left:{

            }
        },
        section:{
            selectedSection: null
        }

    };

    return this.appStatus;

};
```

This will **always** return this object of this.appStatus with the activeOption defined as 'datax'. You should define it with its defaults outside of the get function or check to see if it is null.

```
// Status
this.appStatus = {

        menu:{
            right:{
                activeOption: 'datax'
            },
            left:{

            }
        },
        section:{
            selectedSection: null
        }

      };
this.get = function(){
      return this.appStatus;
}
```

Comment: That's true. I didn't realize, so obvious. As soon as I test I'll give to you the answer. Thanks.